# characters replaced in the filename when downloaded

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Working o an webapi application with angularJS as UI.
When I download a file to my desktop from my application. The name is changed replacing some characters like 'é','ü' with characters like these Ã©.
The code used to donwload the file is the following.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("{documentid}/raw", Order = 5)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDocumentRaw(string documentid)
    {
      var service = ResolveService<IDocumentService>();
      var raw = service.GetRaw(documentid);

      if (raw.Data == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }

      var fileName = raw.FileName?.GetCleanFileName();
      var contentType = raw.ContentType;
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
      {
        fileName = "rawdata";
      }
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType))
      {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
      }

      var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      Stream stream = new MemoryStream(raw.Data);
      response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
      response.Content.Headers.Remove("content-type");
      response.Content.Headers.Add("content-type", contentType);
      response.Content.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
      response.Content.Headers.Add("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
      response.Content.Headers.Remove("x-filename");
      response.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);

      return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
```

In the UI side, this function is used to download the file.

```
$download: function(propertyTypeKey) {
            $http
              .get(this.url + '/raw', {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                params: {
                  propertyTypeKey: propertyTypeKey
                }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                DownloadService.downloadFile(
                  response.data,
                  response.headers('content-type'),
                  response.headers('x-filename')
                );
              });
          },
```

Is this something related to textformat encoding ? Should I add some configuration in the Http Response ? Or may be it is related to the configuration of the IIS Server ? 
I firstly suspected my chrome navigator but I'm facing the same issue on IE.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Comment: The character set of `filename`is very limited; you can use `filename*`.  Especially this answer to the above question should give you a lot of details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745788/642579